# D3 - Anyway to get subset of columns given headers name?

Tags: d3.js

I have been stuck at trying to achieve this for quite some time now. I wanted to get a subset of columns given a header name, but at the same time preserving the data as csv object.

Assuming I have this csv:

```
type,Alabama,Alaska,Arizona,Arkansas
violent,14324,3498,21161,9181
murder,228,16,248,103
rape,1154,553,1534,874
robbery,3576,599,6132,1892
assault,9433,2330,13247,6312
property,110445,17776,181403,74226
burglary,26399,1924,37936,19363
larceny,77067,14577,129979,51346
motorTheft,6979,1275,13488,3517
arson,24,121,1028,307
```

How do I slice it and get only Alaska and Arkansas:

```
type,Alaska,Arkansas
violent,14324,
murder,228,16,
rape,1154,553
robbery,3576,5992
assault,9433,2330
property,110445,17776
burglary,26399,1924
larceny,77067,14577
motorTheft,6979,1275
arson,24,121
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've loaded your *CSV* contents via `d3.csv` (or `d3.csvParse`):

```
const data = d3.csvParse(`type,Alabama,Alaska,Arizona,Arkansas
  violent,14324,3498,21161,9181
  murder,228,16,248,103
  rape,1154,553,1534,874
  robbery,3576,599,6132,1892
  assault,9433,2330,13247,6312
  property,110445,17776,181403,74226
  burglary,26399,1924,37936,19363
  larceny,77067,14577,129979,51346
  motorTheft,6979,1275,13488,3517
  arson,24,121,1028,307`);
```

And considering the following array of columns to keep:

```
const keep = ['Alaska', 'Arkansas'];
```

You could get away with a simple `map` and `reduce` operation, as follows:

```
const sliced = data.map(row => ['type', ...keep].reduce((acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v]: row[v] }), {}));
```

Here, `sliced` would only contain the columns of your *CSV* file corresponding to `'Alaska'` and `'Arkansas'`:

```
[ { type: 'violent', Alaska: '3498', Arkansas: '9181' },
  { type: 'murder', Alaska: '16', Arkansas: '103' },
  { type: 'rape', Alaska: '553', Arkansas: '874' },
  { type: 'robbery', Alaska: '599', Arkansas: '1892' },
  { type: 'assault', Alaska: '2330', Arkansas: '6312' },
  { type: 'property', Alaska: '17776', Arkansas: '74226' },
  { type: 'burglary', Alaska: '1924', Arkansas: '19363' },
  { type: 'larceny', Alaska: '14577', Arkansas: '51346' },
  { type: 'motorTheft', Alaska: '1275', Arkansas: '3517' },
  { type: 'arson', Alaska: '121', Arkansas: '307' } ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Although this question has been well answered, there is another (imo) more tailored way to manipulate this JS array of objects -- using the brilliant [JSONata](http://jsonata.org) expression evaluator library:

```
var jsonata = require('jsonata');
var expr = jsonata('$.$sift(function($v, $k) {$k = "type" or $k in ["Alaska", "Arkansas"]})');
var results = expr.evaluate(csvdata);
```

The built-in `$sift(...)` function returns only fields that match the predicate function -- but there are many other ways to slice and dice Javascript data. The [lambda function syntax](http://docs.jsonata.org/index.html) takes a bit of time to wrap your head around, but it is time well spent for anyone needing to tranform JS data.

There is even an online data exerciser where you can paste your own data, type in an expression, and see the results instantly. Here is an [example](http://try.jsonata.org/HyKXXXndG) using your own data, and the expression above. Enjoy!

-- Steve

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it after giving it several go again!

For those who are stumbled upon this post and have the issue as me, this is how I solved it:

```
var select1 = "Alaska",
    select2 = "Arkansas";

headerBar = ["type"];   
headerBar.push(select1,select2);

var newStateData = data.map(function(dat){
    return {type:dat.type,
            [select1]: dat[select1],
            [select2]: dat[select2]
            }
    });

newStateData["columns"] = headerBar;
```

Have a good day!

**EDIT:** ccjmne posted at the same time as I did, but he does have an more elegant solution. So please refer to his answer.